# remove blank values from array and suggest a better method to read text file data delimited by '|'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am trying to get values from a text file in which entries are delimited using '**|**'.am getting the values using string .Split method..but in some places the delimiter appears multiple times in succession like '**||||||||**',so empty space gets inserted in the array how should i remove those empty elements from array or is there any efficient technique to read values from text file delimited by '|".below is my code and the screen shot of array values

```
 var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"d:\er.txt"));
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
            var values = line.Split('|');
            string[] ee = values;

        }
```

[image: array with empty values in between]

**can any one suggest a better method for reading data from text file delimited by '|'**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) has an overload that takes a [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) enumeration value:

```
var values = line.Split(new char[]{'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will remove empty entries.

Comment: darn, beat me to it (in fact, the system wouldn't let me submit it because it was char-for-char identical)

Comment: Faster than me :-) I'll ditch my answer as it'll clutter up the thread.

Comment: @MarcGravell - char-for-char? Wow. I guess what they say about a million monkeys is true ;)

Comment: @Oded what am i missing here  var values = line.Split('|',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);                The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Oded, when I am trying the code part which you have given here its showing some type of error message like : "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params[] char)' has some invalid arguments" . Why so??

Comment: @Oded var values =  line.Split(new char[]{'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);   this works

Answer (score 1):

You can use [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746) on your array?

```
var values = line.Split("|").Where(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v));
```

Comment: It can make your life a lot easier in a lot of cases but in this case, the number one answer is much nicer!

Comment: it wil be helpful for me if u post some link of linq tutorial..thank you

Comment: I did...click on the "linq" word in my post.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Glad I could help somehow on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

See, the below line of codes, you can do something like that.

```
   var values = line.Split('|');
    List<string> FilteredValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (value != "")
        {
            FilteredValues.Add(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

further to Oded's answer this is the correct syntax

```
 var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"d:\er.txt"));
      while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      {
        var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
        var values =  line.Split(new char[]{'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] ee = values;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, maybe, you can use the trim() function !?